# PostgreSQL Escape Microsoft Special Characters In Select Query

Tags: postgresql, csv, salesforce

PostgreSQL, DBvisualizer and Salesforce

I'm selecting records from a database table and exporting them to a csv file: comma-separated and UTF8 encoded.  I send the file to a user who is uploading the data into Saleforce.  I do not know Salesforce, so I'm totally ignorant on that side of this.  She is reporting that some data in the file is showing up as gibberish (non UTF8) characters (see below).

It seems that some of our users are copy/pasting emails into a web form which then inserts them into our db.  Dates from the email headers (I believe) are the text that are showing as gibberish.

`11‎/‎17‎/‎2015‎ ‎7‎:‎26‎:‎26‎ ‎AM`

becomes

`â€Ž11â€Ž/â€Ž16â€Ž/â€Ž2015â€Ž â€Ž07â€Ž:â€Ž26â€Ž:â€Ž26â€Ž â€ŽAM`

The text in the db field looks normal.  It's when it is exported to a csv file and then that file is viewed in a text-editor like Wordpad or Salesforce.  Then she sees the odd characters.

This only happens with dates from the text that is copy/pasted into the form/db. I have no idea how, or if there is a way, remove these "unseen" characters.

It's the same three-characters each time: `â€Ž`  I did a regex_replace() on these to strip them out, but it doesn't work.  I think since they are not seen in the db field, the regex does see them.

It seems like even though I cannot see these characters, they must be there in some form that is making them show in text-editors like Wordpad or the Salesforce client after being exported to csv.

I can probably do a mass search/find/replace in the text editor, but it would be nice to do this in the sql and avoid the extra step each time.

Hoping someone has seen this and knows an easy fix.

Thanks for any ideas or pointers that may help.

Answer (score 0):

The sequence `â€Ž` is a [left-to-right mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left-to-right_mark), encoded in UTF-8 (as `0xE2 0x80 0x8E`), but being read as if it were in [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252).

A left-to-right mark is invisible, so the fact that you can't see it in the database suggests that it's encoded correctly, but without knowing precisely what path the data took after that, it's hard to guess exactly where it was misinterpreted.

In any case, you should be able to replace the character in your Postgres query by using its Unicode escape sequence: `E'\u200E'`